# Creating Google Chrome shortcut with --disable-web-security

Tags: google-chrome

I am trying to access some local files via jqueryMobile, it works fine in Firefox and IE but Chrome gives a security exception. I can open Chrome in disabled security mode to access local files by using

```
C:\Program Files\Chrome\Chrome.exe --disable-web-security
```

or run it via this

```
chrome.exe --disable-web-security
```

but is there any way I can create a shortcut on desktop that will always open Chrome in disabled security mode?

Comment: Take a look at [Adding Command-Line Switches To Windows Shortcuts](http://superuser.com/questions/358565/adding-command-line-switches-to-windows-shortcuts) on superuser.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Just clone the shortcut for chrome you have on your desktop, and then in the shortcut properties add the parameter `--disable-web-security` (and `--user-data-dir`) at the end of chrome executable path

e.g

```
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="C:\tmpChromeSession"
```

Edit #1 : I changed google chrome path, the old one was not correct.
I just tried it on XP with fresh Chrome installed, but i got a error message that this flag is not supported.

Edit #2 : http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Comment: You shouldn't accept the answer if it doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: LMAO. Also, OP is looking for CHRMOE without cors, not Chrome. Can you install the Internet please?

Comment: @user7527943 s answer below worked better, as it contains --user-data-dir directory which is now required

Answer (score 18):

First search `Run`, then try this:

```
chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security
```

Comment: This did it for me! Open Run tool in windows, by searching run in the search bar, and insert the code as is!

Comment: simple and straight forward

Answer (score 6):

For MAC (ios)

Run following command in terminal.

> open -n -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --args --user-data-dir="/tmp/chrome_dev_test" --disable-web-security

Answer (score 5):

just a quick update, now you need not only --disable-web-security but --user-data-dir
to sum it up:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --user-data-dir`

Comment: DO NOT run this without a path assigned to `user-data-dir`.  The reason this argument is required is to prevent users from disabling web security in the default profile that (presumably) is signed into Facebook / Google / your bank / etc etc.  You should always explicitly specify the path for a dev-only profile.

Answer (score 3):

You must use the following flags

```
--disable-web-security 
--user-data-dir
```

but also pass the path to your chrome user profile

See this:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/9nHBcjNW384
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=575690

So now i have top pass my user profile path:

```
C:\Users\user\projects\project>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\App
lication\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="C:\Users\user\A
ppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default"
```

Comment: I don't pass my user profile path and it works just fine. maybe there's an internal default setting?

Comment: This is the only way that worked for me. In my case, it didn't work until I specified the user data dir

Answer (score 2):

It's working You have to add that parameter  **--disable-web-security** in Target location after one space

Answer (score 2):

**Goto window search type Run**

then on the run popup

just paste "`chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security` "

and ok || worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

For `Windows10`:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="C:\temp"
```

Comment: This is the old method. You have to also use `--user-data-dir="..."` after the above commands.

Answer (score 1):

Now it's

--disable-web-security --user-data-dir="c:/someFolderName"

Answer (score 1):

chrome security command 
for windows open run->than paste this command and make sure you have to close all windows before run this command

"chrome --disable-web-security --user-data-dir"

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu,

```
google-chrome --args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="Path_To_Project_Directory"
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating Google Chrome
Ubuntu
Windows10
chrome.exe --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=c:\my-chrome-data\data

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try with **Safari browser?** It is simple to disable web security over there.

Simply click on

```
Develop > Disable Cross-Origin Restrictions
```

in the menu bar.

In order to get Develop menu, do the following:

```
Preferences > Advanced > Show Develop menu in menu bar.
```

Comment: While this answer is might be good enough it has no link with Google Chrome that has been mentioned in question.