# Infinite scroll with $http get in ionic framework

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I just need to do an ajax infinite scroll in my application, so I used infinite scroll in ionic framework.

My jquery controller code.

```
$scope.moredata = false;
$scope.page = 1;
$scope.loadMoreData=function()
{
  $http.get('someurl?page='+$scope.page).
    success(function(data, status, headers, configure) {
        $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
        $scope.page += 1;
        $scope.product = data;
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert("error");
    });
};
```

My html code.

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item class="item item-thumbnail-left" ng-repeat="(key,value) in product" href="#/app/playlists/{{playlist.id}}">
            <img ng-src={{value.image_url}}>
            <h2>{{value.name}}</h2>
            <p>Sku : {{value.sku}}</p>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    <ion-infinite-scroll distance="20%" on-infinite="loadMoreData()" ng-if="!moredata"></ion-infinite-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

When i used the above code i got page1 values from the server and it is added in my ion-list but when i scroll down the page2 request send and i got response but the listview is not added its is overriding and also the scroll event doesn't stops it calls to the page3, page4 and so on without going to the end of the screen.

Can any one help me how to use the infinite scroll in ionic framework to get data from server dynamically by page wise and append the response while scrolling at the end.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you testing this ? Emulator, browser (With ripple or not ?), directly on a device ?

Comment: I am testing it in Emulator

Comment: Launch `ionic serve` in the project folder (through console). It'll launch it in a browser. We'll see hat happens tough

Comment: i got cross origin error when i use ionic serve in firefox browser :/

Comment: Can you put here what the consoles outputs ?

Comment: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at (url)?page=1. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing). The error i got in console.

Comment: Ok, got something. Wait a min ;)

Comment: Try this, add this plugin : `cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist` and then, in the config.xml, add this `<allow-intent href="someurl/*" />`
Replace `someurl` by the good one ofc.

Comment: again the same error comes in browser but in emulator i got values but i face the above problems while getting values.

Comment: To be honest, i didn't understand what you just said x). You may update your post ?

Comment: i have edited my question now check it

Comment: May be stupid, but try this : `$scope.product += data;` instead of your `$scope.product = data;`

Comment: For `CORS`, check if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29120301/4412363

Comment: Did you get this sorted in the end?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in that line :

```
  $scope.product = data;
```

You are not merging results but overiding your results.
As I don't know how your data are build, it's difficult to suggest you a method to merge

You can see that post here for some suggestion : https://stackoverflow.com/a/17243064/3687474