# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.[ReactJS-Axios-Spring Boot]

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, spring-mvc, axios

When I make a request from **Postman**, I get an error, but when I make a Post request from a **React page**, I get an error.
I **am not** using **Spring Security**.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/createData' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

**React axios code:**

```
return axios.post("http://localhost:8080/api/createData", {
            name: 'Michael'
          });
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>test1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>test1</name>
    <description>Test1 project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Cotroller class for Request:**

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class Tutorial {

  @PostMapping("/createData")
  public void createData(@RequestBody Data data) {
      System.out.println(data.getName());
  }
}
```

I did some research but couldn't figure it out. I get an error when requesting from postman.
Why does the problem occur and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please try to open your react page in chrome tab after disabling Same origin policy.

Comment: @Avilash How Can I do that?

Comment: You can try with : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome 
or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24290149/creating-google-chrome-shortcut-with-disable-web-security

Comment: for Linux When I try ****google-chrome --disable-site-isolation-trials --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="~/tmp"***
, it works in the opened browser, but when I close the browser and open it, it does not work and it does not work in firefox. Can you explain what is the cause of this problem?

Comment: What error coming with postman?

Comment: @RohitAgarwal No problem with Postman.

Comment: Thanks for feedback, When I added the @CrossOrigin notation to the method in my RestController class, the problem was fixed. But I did not fully understand the problem. I guess I need to review a few documents.

Comment: Hi Resul, I have added info link in my answer too. You can have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the cors error due to different ports.
It will not give CORS error if the protocol, host and port is the same.
You can try to disable Same origin policy in chrome and try to open it.
You can find more info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Answer (score 0):

When I added the @CrossOrigin notation to the method in my RestController class, the problem was fixed.

```
@CrossOrigin
@PostMapping("/createData")
  public void createData(@RequestBody Data data) {
      System.out.println(data.getName());
  }
```